# How can I report the Lua stack trace safely when crashes happened?

Tags: android, c++, ios, lua, crashlytics

If the code that Lua invoked in C++ contains an invalid pointer, a crash may happen. But the unwinded stack trace only contains C++ function like 'lua_xxxx'. It is hard to determine what happened without the Lua stack trace.

I want to report the Lua stack trace to our server when the client crashed. But there are some problems I'm not very sure about.

1. If the heap or stack is messed up by invalid memory writing, how can I read the Lua stack trace safely without a secondary crash?
2. Usually, the crash handler function is invoked in another process. Is it safe to get the Lua VM from the main thread?

What I am trying is to get the Lua VM in Crash Handler process and use the following code:

```
luaL_traceback(L, L, NULL, 1);
const char* s = lua_tostring(L, -1);
```

But it will cause a secondary crash in some cases.

The alternative plan I'm thinking about is to read the raw memory of Lua stack with point + offset or dump the stack info into a specific memory section on every Lua invoke. But both of them are not ideal. They will lead to extra performance cost or potential crash risks.

Comment: I don't think Lua has this built-in.